# Is it possible to prevent JSX comment from adding a 'children' element, potentially breaking types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

Let's say I have a third party library like this:

```js
declare var SomeComponentFromLibrary: React.FC<{
    children?: React.ReactElement
}>;
```

Where `children` is defined to be a `React.ReactElement`, and I can't change that fact.

Now, let's say I use it, with a component `<MyComponent />` that happens to generate a type error, and I wish to suppress the error for the timebeing:

```js
<SomeComponentFromLibrary>
    {/* @ts-expect-error */}
    <MyComponent />
</SomeComponentFromLibrary>
```

This creates 2 items in `SomeComponentFromLibrary`'s `children`, (the comment `{}` and `<MyComponent`), while SomeComponentFromLibrary's type definition expects only one child, yielding this:

```
Type '{ children: any[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ children?: ReactElement.... }'.
```

Is it possible at all to use typescript `@ts-` comments (well, or any other comments) in ~~JSX without creating actual children?~~

**EDIT:**

Looks like when I add the comment, it doesn't change the resulting JavaScript `((React.createElement(SomeComponentFromLibrary, null, React.createElement(MyComponent, null))))` -- But for some reason, TypeScript still complains (things that `children` is `any[]`). I think this could be a bug in TS -- maybe it parses JSX differently?

Comment: `{null/*comment*/}` or `React.ReactElement[]`, pretty sure you wont be able to solve this other way :-(

Comment: As far as I can tell, `{/*...*/}` has no effect whatsoever on what is sent to the component: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/qLspfmxc/ It doesn't, for instance, make it that there are multiple children in your example. There is one child: `<MyComponent />`. (I had to try it to be sure. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ah, you're right! I get `export default () => (React.createElement(SomeComponentFromLibrary, null,
    React.createElement(MyComponent, null)));` without the extra child being passed in! This has to be a TS issue then, not the JSX -> JS compilation?

Comment: If you're actually getting an error because of it, yeah, that seems like either a bug or a feature they haven't implemented yet. (I could swear that `{/*...*/}` didn't used to work in JSX -- expressions used to *have* to have a value -- but it has worked lately, so...) You'll want to double-check you're completely up-to-date on TS. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript comment directives are not very JSX friendly, sadly. But you can definitely make it work.

Give it one child, in braces, `{ }`, with the comment in those braces.

```
<SomeComponentFromLibrary>
    {/* @ts-expect-error */
        <MyComponent />
    }
</SomeComponentFromLibrary>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrgGVckBhXSapamAMRwgAMsABGUFFACeACgDeaABbAANgBMi1AL4AuOHLhLVGnnuToYAOnMYAoiqQgeMLQEp9pOF7hEYlKIwAPAB8CsrqmlqBAPTBpFrk0dFwAJLUAG4oKsBqPsTwaJwMznCiSGgolADOSHDA8GoQSFVw1BDwvv7UlhQ0dAxwALJSHODFvDLucgm9tDD0jADiEBBqkx7eeX4BcDKem96BLE6jXM4CuCLiklJxB-f60QBUcAACMFUAtEgAHmDlMG+UBwUDgT2i+weD0Cw1O43gsUhULgCShMWO7CK3F4F2EYgk0ju3lc8XIVDmCzgACEUGspkjOjs9miMXDsfxBFcCbckVC5M83h9vn8AUCQWDoqjkV4YSMsSVEWjoqz5TjOfibkSvCSEkA)

---

Also, side note: The typings of `SomeComponentFromLibrary` are probably just *wrong*. In nearly all cases I've ever seen, `children` should be typed as `React.ReactNode`. And when you type this function as such, it [now works exactly like you expect.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSB6CuNAC2ABsATIgOwC5FiYA6ZdGADkITJKUwBXVhmARWcAMq4kAYVyRWSVjABiOEABlgAIygooATwAUAbzqMWWgL6cbNeszad+GPt2GiTgCUcG6kcBFwRDASUPIAPAB8dh6OrE7xFImkTuRUcACSrABuKAzATFHcNOpyWvDGSGgoEgDOSHDA8EwQSK1wrBDw0bGsPOJSMnJwALIWauB12lYhNrkT0jCy8jrAAB5ITCuh4ZEjcXBWp5GR8UogqrWa2nq4RqbmFtk3P5E2FAAqOAAARgrQAtEg9mAmjBIVAcFA4ACKLlfr94nMFhp6nAstcfpl7o9Fs9dPp3mZLN9IkEcqQgA)

So I'd probably create a pull request for whatever this library is to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41125

It's fixed here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41166 and should be released either in 4.1 or 4.2